# I am unable to pass the screen right after choosing (Debian GNU/Linux Live Kernel 4.19.0-6-686)

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I am sort of new here so I would try to explain my problem as precise as possible, am running HP ENVY X2 PC with the following details:

Total Memory: 2 GB BIOS Version: F.07 BIOS Vendor: Insyde Windows Version: 10 Factory Installed OS: Windows 8 Bit: 32 bit Processor: X86

with that out of the way, my machine only supports EFI, and not UEFI, as far as I looked up only Debian variants have the EFI support, I flashed via Rufus multiple ISOs for USB Flash Drive, the flashing process is certainly correct, now on booting options I select my USB Flash Drive with the ISO image on it, I get to a screen with multiple options the first one is (Debian GNU/Linux Live Kernel 4.19.0-6-686), I select it and then I get presented with a screen with no options and nothing to check on, attached in this message, i left it for 6 hours, and nothing ever progressed, I tried multiple Debian variants and they are listed below: 1. debian-10.2.0-i386-netinst 2. debian-live-10.2.0-i386-lxde 3. debian-live-10.2.0-i386-xfce nonfree

they all resulted in the same outcome, I have been trying to work out this problem for over than 48 hours with constant failure, any help would be highly appreciated[image: ![the screen where its stuck and pressing any keys combo wont do anything, complete dead screen]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwWVa.jpg)

Comment: In the menu, there should be an option to edit the menu entry -- probably the `e` key. If you do that, remove the `-quiet` option if you see it, so you'll get all the output from the start-up process on screen. Perhaps `CTRL`+`ALT`+`1` will do the same; this is normally the terminal where the output goes. Without it, all you can do is make blind guesses on what goes wrong; you won't see any warnings or errors show up.

Comment: hey bro, thanks for your replay, which menu are you referring to? and based on the details I explained which Debian variant do you advise me to install?

Comment: You should get a boot menu after your initial (BIOS) boot options, that comes with options like *boot the live system*, or *install Debian*, or *choose language* etc. It is the second menu you refer to, which is the last one before you get that persistent background image without any further activity. (the menu where you wrote the first option is "*Debian GNU/Linux Live Kernel 4.19.0-6-686*")

Comment: thank you so much I will try that out and let you know.

Comment: Bro I tried doing what you said and I removed the Quite word but still its the same frozen page and no keys would bring up anything, this is really frustrating

Answer (score 0):

On the HP website, the HP ENVY X2 is advertised as follows:

> *The notebook that doubles as a tablet. The new HP ENVY x2 PC gives you the power of two devices in one.*

Looking at the specifications of one of such devices, the "*HP ENVY x2 - 12-e001tu*", I found that it features the "*Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 835 (2.2 GHz, up to 2.6 GHz, 8 cores)*" processor. Looking further at the details of the processor, it turns out that this is a 64-bit processor based on the **ARM** architecture, not the x86 architecture. So that means that none of the kernels of the installation images you used support the processor you have, hence the immediate failure to boot.

So if you want to run Debian on it, you will have to go to https://www.debian.org/CD/, where you can download an installation image, but this time download an image for the ***arm64*** architecture, not for the *i386* architecture. Then follow the process you went through previously up to the point where booting up failed.

If you go for your first option, the netinstall, the downloaded image should have the filename:

"debian-10.2.0-**arm64**-netinst.iso"

That should make it work out for you.  Any further issues, feel free to return to this site for further assistance.

Comment: I see what you mean, downloading a arm64 based ISO will get my BIOS to fail on detecting the USB Stick, as far as the processor is concerned looking into my hardware details its in Intel Atom Z2760 1.80 GHZ with 2GB RAM, I will be honest with you I have litreally done everything I could to  get this mysterious machine to run, but in vein.

Comment: I also placed a bootia32.efi in EFI/BOOT, it detected my stick, hitting install or any other option from the installation boot screen  does nothing, am starting to believe that my BIOS dont support 64bit UEFI, but even the images from debian for 32bit they had bootia32.efi as well as grubia32.efi, this is such an enigma really.

Comment: What I don't get, to be fair, is how both Windows 8 and Windows 10 are installed, if I get the info correctly.  I was also a bit surprised to see a 32-bit OS instead of a 64-bit one, but just saw on the CPU spec sheet that it's a 32-bit CPU. One thing I can suggest at the moment is to see if an older Debian(-based) distro works, for example Jessie (Debian 8), or Knoppix. Older CD images can be found at https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/.

Comment: Update: I tried **debian-8.11.1-i386-netinst** i got to debian installation screen selected Graphical Install and normal Install, stuck at the boot logo of Debian.